# Anonymous function with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to create an anonymous function that takes in a source and allows me to specify a destination, I am having some issues with it. It's complaining that my destination is "Type" which makes sense but I am not sure how to fix it.

Here is the function:

```
    public TDest ReadService<TSrc,TDest>(Func<IWebApiServiceResponse<TSrc>> func, TDest dest)
    {
        // i will be doing other functionality in here, error logging, etc
        return Mapper.Map(func(), dest);
    }
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
var data = ReadService(() => Services.CServices.CUsers(), typeof(CustomViewModel));
```

I am expecting data to be of type CustomViewModel.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's not *completely* clear what you're trying to do, but I suspect you need to pass a view model itself instead of the *type of* the view model:

```
var data = ReadService(() => Services.CServices.CUsers(), new CustomViewModel());
```

or let AutoMapper create one for you:

```
public TDest ReadService<TSrc,TDest>(Func<IWebApiServiceResponse<TSrc>> func)
{
    // i will be doing other functionality in here, error logging, etc
    return Mapper.Map<IWebApiServiceResponse<TSrc>, TDest>(func());
}
```

Note, however, that the generic parameter can't be inferred from the return type, so you'd have to specify it when calling the method:

```
var data = ReadService<CUser,CustomViewModel>(() => Services.CServices.CUsers());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing some concepts here:

When you make the call `ReadService(() => Services.CServices.CUsers(), typeof(CustomViewModel))`, generic type `TDest` will be `System.Type` since thats what `typeof` returns.

So the return type of `ReadService` is `System.Type` and you are trying to map from `IWebApiServiceResponse<...>` to `System.Type`, not `CustomViewModel`.

To fix this, you can do something like this:

```
public TDest ReadService<TSrc, TDest>(Func<IWebApiServiceResponse<TSrc>> func)
{
    var type = typeof(TDest); //If you need the System.Type of TDest

    ...
    return Mapper.Map<TDest>(func());
}

var data = ReadService</*source type*/, CustomViewModel>(() => Services.CServices.CUsers());
```